# Drobo doesn't power up after Windows7 hibernation

Tags: windows-7, hibernate, drobo

I am using a Drobo on a 64bit Windows7 Professional system. Often, when waking from hibernate mode, the Drobo doesn't power up. I have the latest (1.3.7) firmware in the Drobo.

Anyone know of a fix?

Comment: How is the Drobo connected to the PC? USB? Edit your original question to include this new information, the model number of the Drobo also.

Answer (score 0):

(from drobo's website)

If your Drobo device is a Drobo FS, Drobo S, DroboPro or DroboElite, you can change the spin down time. In Drobo Dashboard, click Advanced Controls -> Tools -> Settings. Under the General tab, you will see the Disk Drive Spin Down slider. You can set this to best suit your needs. On DroboElite, the default is Never. On the other Drobo products that include this feature, the default is 15 minutes.

Note: Drobo employs this life-prolonging feature whether or not it is directly connected to a host computer or uses DroboShare.

Mac users have reported this same thing happening -  like Moab suggested - let us know the model number and connection type for better trouble shooting